# Binary file read in as string and stored as Base64

Tags: java, android, string, base64, binaryfiles

I have an issue with a legacy program. The program reads a file from disk as string and encodes the file as Base64 and saves the file to disk. The problem is that the file read in is a binary file. Is there any way to reverse this process?

Here is the offending line of code:

```
String sig = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(
    utility.readFileAsString(file.getPath()).getBytes(),
    android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
```

We have update the application to read the file in as bytes but that doesn't help with the files already created.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Are you asking how to reverse the encoding? Or how to identity files that are encoded?

Comment: There are some overloaded `decode()` methods in [`Base64`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Base64-decode the files into Strings, and then call String.getBytes(), or String.getBytes(charset) if you know what charset `utility.readFileAsString()` used, but you have to accept the probability that many if not all of the files are corrupt.

Comment: It looks like anything over a 127 has been lost.